# Which is the immutable/un-changable date attribute of file

Tags: c#, exe

I have a scenario where I want to get the actual created date of file. Like if I created file on 08/04/2022 6:27PM I always want to get that exact date.

I tried many method all is changing the date attribute of file.
I do not want that. Can anyone please tell me what is the attribute of file which do not change
for whatever condition??[image]

Comment: Date created is your best bet, others would change definitely. Mind you, when you copy a file to different folder or drive, that will change as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I want the immutable date column for file. I have already tried this

Comment: If Date created does not work for then no other will. There is no guaranteed immutable field with such info.

Comment: "I tried many method all is changing the date attribute of file." I don't follow; are you saying creation date just spontaneously changes? Are you seeing the same thing happen in Windows explorer? Is this related to a specific file or a specific file system or device? Is this related to a certain way of working, like copying files between locations? Can you give a detailed example, together with the code you used?

Comment: I have switched between many drive and folders , I tried to shift the files using the my hard disk, I tried sending files in to the mail as well as google drive.

Comment: The attributes you show are part of the used filesystem not part of the file. If you need them to move around with the file you need them as part of the actual file like certain image formats do.